# Javascript from Typescript error =>Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: typescript

I  get this define statement at the top of the game.js file (from the game.ts compilation) :

```
define(["require", "exports", "GameObjects"], function(require, exports, __GameObjects__) {
var GameObjects = __GameObjects__;

$(document).ready(function () {
    var game = new Game();
    $(document).keydown(game.onKeyDown);
    $(document).keyup(game.onKeyUp);
    $(document).keyup(game.onKeyUp);
});
function collides(a, b) {
```

and this error: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

from this page:

```
    <head>
    <title>Space Demo</title>
    <link href="/stylesheets/screen.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />


    <script language="javascript" src="javascripts/require.js" type="text/javascript" data-main="ts/game.js"> </script>
    <script language="javascript" src="javascripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>

</head>
```

any ideas?

edit_***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_***

The game class is in thegame.js file

class Game {

```
//  canvas: JQuery;

CANVAS_WIDTH: number = 400;
CANVAS_HEIGHT: number = 400;

FPS: number = 30;

enemies = [];
playerBullets: Array = new Array[40];
player: GameObjects.GameObjects.Player;


canvas: HTMLCanvasElement = <HTMLCanvasElement> document.getElementById('canvas');

context2D: CanvasRenderingContext2D;

constructor () {
    // this.canvas = canvas;

    this.context2D = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
    this.canvas.width = this.CANVAS_WIDTH;
    this.canvas.height = this.CANVAS_HEIGHT;

    this.initGame();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is some function you are trying to call, that is not defined/initialized.

- Is the `Game` class accessible from there you are constructing it?
- Is the element with `ID="canvas"` a `<canvas>`-element?
- Does the `Game` class have an `initGame` method?

If you open your page with Google Chrome, and look in the developer console, you should see a stack-trace. This should tell you where the error comes from.

Comment: Sorry but its in the game.ts file